# How can I see my theme's text domain?

Tags: translation, textdomain, xgettext

Where can I discover my current theme's text domain for use with translation ([GetText](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your theme's text domain is defined in your Theme Header in `style.css`. For example:

```
/*
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin
 * Author: Otto
 * Text Domain: my-plugin
 */
```

The text domain should match your theme's 'slug' (ie. the name of the folder where your theme is stored).

Read more: https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Text_Domains